# How to change side of y-axis in histogram?

Tags: graphics, histogram, stata

If I use the `hist` command without any specifications or options, I get a histogram, where the only y-axis is located on the right side. I searched the web for options to change it to the left side, but all I could find was about a second y-axis or the title of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this script

```
sysuse auto, clear
set scheme s1color
hist mpg
hist mpg, ysc(alt)
```

you should see

1. The default in which the y axis is on the left.
2. An alternative in which it is on the right.

These are standard options for `graph twoway` documented from `help hist` under `two_way_options`, in turn under `axis_options`, `axis_scale_options`.

All the help you need is included with the Stata version you are using. Googling is inefficient here.